# Mysql Update table1 from table2 values with CASE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have table A & Table B . I need to update TableA.custid , with values (1 - 8 ) so I can reflect TableB.names

To make it more clear

TableA.custid = 1 , when TableB.name = 'Allen Gray'
TableA.custid = 2 , when TableB.name = 'Alex Watt'

TableA and TableB got the same number of records. And the relation between the 2 would be TableA.id = TableB.id

What would be the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tableA as t1 inner join TableB as t2
on t1.id=t2.id
set t1.name=t2.name
```